# Problem with PHP (works on localhost, but errors on web server)

Tags: php, html

am having some trouble with PHP on the webserver I am using.
I am sure the answer is obvious but for some reason it is eluding me completely.

I have a php file which uploads two files, a before and an after shot of the client.
The script on my server(localhost) works fine, it uploads the files, renames the files to a timestamp and puts the images into there folders for further sorting by another script.

Yet when I upload it to the webserver, and some files work (i.e mel.jpg, test.jpg) but files like IMG_0042.jpg do not work, Im sure the answer is something simple, but is completely eluding me.

Im thinking the underscore may have something to do with it, but cannot for the life of my figure it out, any help greatly appreciated, 
thanks very much.

```
<?php 

if(!isset($_COOKIE['auth'])) {
header("Location: login12.php");
exit();
} 

$page_title="test";
include('header.html');

// Upload and Rename File

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
$filenamebef = $_FILES["uploadbef"]["name"];
$filenameaft = $_FILES["uploadaft"]["name"];
$file_basename_bef = substr($filenamebef, 0, strripos($filenamebef, '.'));
$file_basename_aft = substr($filenameaft, 0, strripos($filenameaft, '.'));
 // get file extention
$file_ext_bef = substr($filenamebef, strripos($filenamebef, '.')); 
$file_ext_aft = substr($filenameaft, strripos($filenameaft, '.')); 
// get file name
$filesize_bef = $_FILES["uploadbef"]["size"];
$filesize_aft = $_FILES["uploadaft"]["size"];
$allowed = array('image/pjpeg','image/jpeg','image/JPG','image/X-PNG','image/PNG','image   /png','image/x-png');

    if ((in_array($_FILES['uploadbef']['type'], $allowed)) && in_array($_FILES['uploadaft']['type'], $allowed)) {       

        if (($filesize_bef < 200000) && ($filesize_aft < 200000)){

            // rename file

            $date = date("mdy");
            $time = date("His");

            $timedate = $time . $date;

            $newfilenamebef = $timedate . $file_ext_bef;
            $newfilenameaft = $timedate . $file_ext_aft;

            if ((file_exists("upload/images/before" . $newfilenamebef)) && (file_exists("uploads/images/after" . $newfilenameaft))) {       
                // file already exists error
                echo "You have already uloaded this file.";         
            } else {        
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadbef"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/images/before/" . $newfilenamebef) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadaft"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/images/after/" . $newfilenameaft);
                echo "File uploaded successfully."; 

            }
        }

    } elseif ((empty($file_basename_bef)) && (empty($file_basename_aft))) { 
        // file selection error
        echo "Please select a file to upload.";     
    } elseif (($filesize_bef > 200000) && ($filesize_aft > 200000)) {   
        // file size error
        echo "The file you are trying to upload is too large.";     
    } else {    
        // file type error
        echo "Only these file typs are allowed for upload: " . implode(', ',$allowed);
        unlink($_FILES["uploadbef"]["tmp_name"]);   
        unlink($_FILES["uploadaft"]["tmp_name"]);   
    }

}

echo $newfilenamebef;
echo $newfilenameaft;

?>



<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploading.php" method="post">

<input type="hidden" value="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="524288">
<fieldset>
<legend>Select a JPEG or PNG image of 512kb or smaller to be uploaded : </legend>
<p><b>Before</b> <input type="file" name="uploadbef" /></p>
<p><b>After</b> <input type="file" name="uploadaft" /></p>
</fieldset>

<div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />

</form>

<?php
include('footer.html');
?>
```

Comment: If you think the underscore is the issue, rename that file without the underscore and try again - at least then you can verify if it is or not to help narrow down the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "do not work"?  Do you get an error message? What is the difference between these files (except for filename)?

Comment: Check max_upload_filesize, and post size on the remote host.

Comment: @AJ - I was about to make that same edit :) Glad that I'm not the only grammar nazi around here

Comment: oh my god, I Found the issue, so sorry for wasting your time, My max file size was set to 200kb whilst the file was 356kb, will update so an error shows for this, still very new to php

Answer (score 3):

You should but these two lines at the top of your index.php or bootstrap.php :

```
error_reporting( -1 );
ini_set( "display_errors" , 1 );
```

And see if some error messages turn up.

It is quite possible that problem is caused by wrong file permissions.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to add to the script instead of php.ini (where they are often forgotten about)

Answer (score 1):

At a quick guess I would say that your localhost is not case sensitive, whereas your webserver is.

In other words, on your localhost IMG_12345.JPG is the same as img_12345.jpg. On your webserver, though, they are treated differently.

Without any actual reported errors, it's hard to be certain, but this is a common problem.

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick reply! Will try that and see how it goes,

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking for valid uploads properly. Something like the following would be FAR more reliable:

```
// this value is ALWAYS present and doesn't depend on form fields
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
    $errmsgs = array();
    if ($_FILES['uploadbef']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $errs++;
        $errmsgs[] = "'uploadebef' failed with code #" . $_FILES['uploadebef']['error'];
    }
    if ($_FILES['uploadaft']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $errs++;
        $errmsgs[] = "'uploadeaft' failed wicode #" . $_FILES['uploadeaft']['error'];
    }
    if (count($errmsgs) > 0) {
       print_r($errmsgs);
       die();
    }
    ... process the files here ...
}
```

As well, why re-invent the wheel to split up the file names?

```
$parts = path_info($_FILES['uploadaft']['name']);
$basename = $parts['basename'];
$ext = $parts['extension'];
```

Comment: hey thanks for those suggestions, will try and implement them into the script now, the splitting of the file names looks ALOT easier then all the excess code I had, thanks again